# Who are the mages of different kingdoms of the Witcher?

Tags: books, the-witcher

In ***The Witcher*** there are many kingdoms and each has its own *mage*. Who are the different mages of the different kingdoms? Some of the famous mages I know are Yennefer, Triss, Sabrina, etc.
 I want the answer to be based on the books.

Comment: Do you mean which realm each mage comes from, or which realm each mage serve as counselor to the King/Ruler?

Comment: I want which realm they are counselor to

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **Yennefer of Vengerberg** - advisor to king King Demavend III of Aedirn
- **Triss Merigold** - advisor to King Foltest
- **Fercart of Cidaris** - advisor to King Foltest
- **Keira Metz** - advisor to King Foltest
- **Stregobor** - advisor to  King Idi of Kovir
- **Drithelm** - advisor to King Esterad of Kovir
- **Philippa Eilhart** - advisor to  King Vizimir of Redania
- **Lytta Neyd** - advisor to King Belohun of Kerack
- **Dethmold** - advisor to King Henselt of Kaedwen
- **Merwin Ademeyn** - advisor to King Henselt of Kaedwen
- **Sabrina Glevissig**  - advisor to King Henselt of Kaedwen
- **Artorius Vigo** - advisor to the Toussaint Royal Family

These are some of the more notable ones. There are many other mages like Fringilla Vigo who are not advisors to kings or monarchs, but do take sides in political affairs.